# Find out EC2 instance associated with Elastic Beanstalk Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to find out what EC2 instance is associated with my Elastic Beanstalk Application from the dashboard?

I have checked every single page under "Configuration" but I couldn't find any info about what EC2 instance is running the application.

Comment: Aren't the instances tagged with the EB application name?

Comment: Yes, but I needed the opposite (to know the instances name from the elastic beanstalk dashboard) :-) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't see the associated EC2 instances via Elastic Beanstalk dashboard.

Go to [EC2 Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances:sort=instanceId) and then search instances by `tag:elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` with your Elastic Beanstalk environment name as the value.

Comment: Additionally you can make an Elastic Beanstalk API call to DescribeEnvironmentResources to find instances associated to your beanstalk environment. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeEnvironmentResources.html
This can be done via SDK or CLI

Comment: You can also look at DescribeInstancesHealth API which provides a paginated list of instance ids along with their health. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeInstancesHealth.html