# How to find historically how many EC2 instances have been spun up by Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an API powered by an Elastic Beanstalk setup with an instance count setting between 1 and 24. Historically when the load become heavier, it did has spun up additional EC2 instances.

We're planning to significantly increase the load to the API, I'm trying to explore current utilisation and scalability of the setup. I'm tackling this with following approach:

1. Get hold of historical API call count & throughputs and I have managed to retrieve the data.
2. Check out historically how many EC2 instances EB has spun up and what're the instance type/size used
3. Workout the relationship between API call count/throughput and EC2 instance count/size.
4. Project the required EC2 instance count/size for the future hence the cost as well.

I'm currently stuck with step 2. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167134/find-out-ec2-instance-associated-with-elastic-beanstalk-application) to identify EC2 instance that's currently used by EB but not sure how to find out the historical data.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can enable extra metrics on the Auto Scaling Group, which will allow you to display the count metrics you are looking for on the Elastic Beanstalk monitoring page.

From the EC2 console, click Auto Scaling Groups in the left-hand navigation and click on the autoscaling group associated with your Elastic Beanstalk application. (If you don't know the auto scaling group, you can find it by clicking on one of the EC2 instances, selecting the Tags tab, and finding the `aws:autoscaling:groupName` value.) After you have selected the correct auto scaling group, click the Monitoring tab, and check the "Auto Scaling group metrics collection: Enable" checkbox.

[image: autoscaling group monitoring tab]

Once that is enabled, go back to the Elastic Beanstalk console, select the environment, and click the Monitoring link in the left-side navigation. In the Monitoring section, click Edit, and in the Add Graph section, select "AWSEBAutoScalingGroup" for the resource. Under the "CloudWatch metric" options, you should now see some new metrics with the "Group" prefix (note that it may take up to 5 minutes for the new metrics to appear):

[image: Elastic Beanstalk monitoring edit page]

You can create a metric with "GroupMaxSize", selecting "Maximum" as the Statistic in order see the instance counts launched by the autoscaler over time.